# When will Callisto be in orbital resonance with the rest of Jupiter's big moons?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, jupiter, orbital-resonance

The [four Gallilean moons of Jupiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moons_of_Jupiter) (from innermost) are Io, Europa, Ganymede, and Callisto.  Io, Europa, and Ganymede are in a 1:2:4 [orbital resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_resonance). Callisto's orbital period is 16.689 days, which is not much more than twice Ganymede's period of 7.1546 days.

[image]

If Jupiter's orbit around the Sun was stable, when could we expect Callisto to come into a 1:2:4:8 orbital resonance with the Jupiter's other Gallilean moons?

Related: [Does anyone know why three of Jupiter's largest moons orbit in 1:2:4 resonance?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/does-anyone-know-why-three-of-jupiters-largest-moons-orbit-in-124-resonance)

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of the one you suggested? But that answer only gives a vague idea of when that happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we tried to answer to this question in this article:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.01106

According to the current estimation of the tidal dissipation in the Jovian system, we expect that Callisto will be captured into resonance in about 1.5 billions of years, forming 1:2:4:8 resonant chain with the other Galilean moons.